# Open MPI Files Can´t Be Found For (RegCM) Installation

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I tried to install a climate modelling programm (RegCM) for which I used Ubuntu on VMware Workstation, GNU fortran compiler and Open MPI.

Like suggested [https://gforge.ictp.it/gf/download/docmanfileversion/35/758/Install_RegCM4.3.pdf] I installed the GNU fortran compiler, Open MPI, unpacked RegCM Version 4.4.5 and configured RegCM (./configure CC=gcc FC=gfortran).
In 'sudo make' the Error

> 'Error: Can't open included file 'mpif.h''

appears. In 'RegCM-4.3.5.8/Main/mpplib' which was searched is no file with that name but one can be found in 'openmpi-1.10.2/ompi/include'. Just to give it a try copied 'mpif.h' in the searched directory. 
It worked but now a new Error appeared:

> 'Can't open included file 'mpif-config.h''

which again can be found in 'openmpi-1.10.2/ompi/include'. Again copied the same Error arised with another file.
I also tried a older Version of RegCM (4.3) with the same effect.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: make[2]: Entering directory '[...]/RegCM-4.3.5.8/Main/mpplib'
gfortran -I[...]/RegCM-4.3.5.8/external -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -I[...]/RegCM-4.3.5.8/Share -O3 -mtune=native -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -c mod_mppparam.F90
mpif.h:55: Error: Can't open included file 'mpif-constants.h'
Makefile:623: recipe for target 'mod_mppparam.o' failed
make[2]: *** [mod_mppparam.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '[...]/RegCM-4.3.5.8/Main/mpplib'
Makefile:602: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

? Which version of Ubuntu are you using ? Like "Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64".

---

mpif.h, mpif-config.h : `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev`

---

Note : RegCM-4.3.5.8 **is buggy**. No luck with '4.3.5.8' here, any contemporary OS. **RegCM-4.5.0** → `RegCM-4.5.0.tar.gz` 
https://gforge.ictp.it/gf/download/frsrelease/252/1580/RegCM-4.5.0.tar.gz builds with no errors : Tested with Ubuntu 16.04 - 64bits and PCLinuxOS2016 -32bits.

---

---

Comment: Now `Can't open included file 'mpif-constants.h'` occurs. And 'mpif-constants.h' is again in 'openmpi-1.10.2/ompi/include'..

Comment: 'mpif-constants.h' is included in libopenmpi-dev : http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libopenmpi-dev/filelist → since Ubuntu version 16.04 → Apr 2016, and in openmpi since version 1.8.... -

Comment: P.s.: I´m using ubuntu 16.04 - intel64